# Creating Annotation Feature Class using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, annotation

I want to create an annotation feature class with arcobjects. I do not want my annotation to be linked to source feature class. I have this code but it is not working. It only creates an empty annotation feature class, no labels in it. I tested every thing that I thought might be the problem. still no success. I have a problem with `CreateAnnotationClass` method. It's not even getting source feature class as a parameter. how does it know which feature class to label in the workspace?! (there is a parameter as srcFeatureClass, but it is only to say if I want my annotation to be linked to source feature class, which I don't, so I put it as null.) can anyone help please?

```
        public IFeatureClass IFeatureWorkspaceAnno_Example(IFeatureClass featureClass)
    {
        IDataset dataset = (IDataset)featureClass;
        //cast for the feature workspace from the workspace
        IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)dataset.Workspace;
        IFeatureWorkspaceAnno featureWorkspaceAnno = dataset.Workspace as IFeatureWorkspaceAnno;
        //set up the reference scale
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IGraphicsLayerScale graphicLayerScale =
            new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.GraphicsLayerScaleClass();
        IGeoDataset geoDataset = (IGeoDataset)dataset;
        graphicLayerScale.Units = ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.esriUnits.esriMeters;
        graphicLayerScale.ReferenceScale = axMapControl1.MapScale; 
        //set up symbol collection
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbolCollection symbolCollection =
            new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SymbolCollectionClass();

        #region "MakeText"
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IFormattedTextSymbol myTextSymbol =
            new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.TextSymbolClass();

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IRgbColor rgbColor = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RgbColorClass();
        rgbColor.Red = 150;
        rgbColor.Green = 0;
        rgbColor.Blue = 0;
        myTextSymbol.Color = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IColor)rgbColor;
        //Set other properties for myTextSymbol
        myTextSymbol.Angle = 0;
        myTextSymbol.RightToLeft = false;
        myTextSymbol.VerticalAlignment = ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.esriTextVerticalAlignment.esriTVABaseline;
        myTextSymbol.HorizontalAlignment = ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.esriTextHorizontalAlignment.esriTHAFull;
        //myTextSymbol.CharacterSpacing = 200;
        myTextSymbol.Case = ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.esriTextCase.esriTCNormal;
        #endregion

        symbolCollection.set_Symbol(0, (ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol)myTextSymbol);
        //set up the annotation labeling properties including the expression
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IAnnotateLayerProperties annoProps = new
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.LabelEngineLayerPropertiesClass();
        annoProps.FeatureLinked = false;
        annoProps.AddUnplacedToGraphicsContainer = true;
        annoProps.CreateUnplacedElements = true;
        annoProps.DisplayAnnotation = true;
        annoProps.UseOutput = true;
        annoProps.LabelWhichFeatures = esriLabelWhichFeatures.esriAllFeatures;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILabelEngineLayerProperties layerEngineLayerProps =
            (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILabelEngineLayerProperties)annoProps;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IAnnotationExpressionEngine annoExpressionEngine =
            new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.AnnotationVBScriptEngineClass();
        layerEngineLayerProps.ExpressionParser = annoExpressionEngine;
        layerEngineLayerProps.Expression = "[OBJECTID]";
        layerEngineLayerProps.IsExpressionSimple = true;
        layerEngineLayerProps.Offset = 0;
        layerEngineLayerProps.SymbolID = 0;
        layerEngineLayerProps.Symbol = myTextSymbol;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IAnnotateLayerTransformationProperties annoLayerTransProp =
            (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IAnnotateLayerTransformationProperties)annoProps;
        annoLayerTransProp.ReferenceScale = graphicLayerScale.ReferenceScale;
        annoLayerTransProp.Units = graphicLayerScale.Units;
        annoLayerTransProp.ScaleRatio = axMapControl1.MapScale;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection annoPropsColl =
            new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.AnnotateLayerPropertiesCollectionClass();
        annoPropsColl.Add(annoProps);
        //use the AnnotationFeatureClassDescription to get the list of required
        //fields and the default name of the shape field
        IObjectClassDescription oCDesc = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.AnnotationFeatureClassDescriptionClass();
        IFeatureClassDescription fCDesc = (IFeatureClassDescription)oCDesc;

        //create the new class
        return featureWorkspaceAnno.CreateAnnotationClass("AnnoTest",
            oCDesc.RequiredFields, oCDesc.InstanceCLSID, oCDesc.ClassExtensionCLSID,
            fCDesc.ShapeFieldName, "", null, null,
            annoPropsColl, graphicLayerScale, symbolCollection, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I wrote the method to copy annotation layer. Maybe you will find this code useful. From annotation layer you can get annotation feature class. You just need create instances of [ISymbolCollection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/isymbolcollection.htm), [IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/iannotatelayerpropertiescollection.htm) and [IOverposterProperties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/ioverposterproperties.htm).

```
    public static IAnnotationLayer CreateAnnotationLayer(IAnnotationLayer templateLayer, string name, IWorkspace workspace, IFeatureDataset featureDataset)
    {
        var templateFeatureClass = (templateLayer as IDisplayTable)?.DisplayTable as IFeatureClass;
        var annotationClassExtension = templateFeatureClass.Extension as IAnnotationClassExtension;

        //

        var symbolCollection = (annotationClassExtension.SymbolCollection as IClone)?.Clone() as ISymbolCollection;
        var annotationProperties = (annotationClassExtension.AnnoProperties as IClone)?.Clone() as IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection;
        var overposterProperties = (annotationClassExtension.OverposterProperties as IClone)?.Clone() as IOverposterProperties;

        //

        IGraphicsLayerScale graphicsLayerScale = new GraphicsLayerScaleClass();
        graphicsLayerScale.ReferenceScale = annotationClassExtension.ReferenceScale;
        graphicsLayerScale.Units = annotationClassExtension.ReferenceScaleUnits;

        //

        IObjectClassDescription ocDescription = new AnnotationFeatureClassDescriptionClass();
        IFeatureClassDescription fcDescription = (IFeatureClassDescription)ocDescription;

        IFields requiredFields = ocDescription.RequiredFields;
        int shapeFieldIndex = requiredFields.FindField(fcDescription.ShapeFieldName);
        IField shapeField = requiredFields.get_Field(shapeFieldIndex);
        IGeometryDef geometryDef = shapeField.GeometryDef;
        IGeometryDefEdit geometryDefEdit = (IGeometryDefEdit)geometryDef;
        geometryDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = (templateFeatureClass as IGeoDataset).SpatialReference;

        //

        IAnnotationLayerFactory annotationLayerFactory = new FDOGraphicsLayerFactoryClass();
        return annotationLayerFactory.CreateAnnotationLayer(
            workspace as IFeatureWorkspace,
            featureDataset,
            name,
            geometryDef,
            null,
            annotationProperties,
            graphicsLayerScale,
            symbolCollection,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            true,
            overposterProperties,
            string.Empty);
    }
```